# Adjust div position fluidly as window width changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with multiple absolute-positioned divs within it. I would like the left position of these inner divs to move fluidly as the window is resized. An example of what I have so far can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/ewqmfa4d/.

How can I do this? I presume I'd use jQuery? Note that I'm not looking for media queries, but rather something that provides fluid movement as the width of the window changes.

Comment: Please update your fiddle. :)

Comment: What do you mean 'move fluidly'? move up? move down? rotate? move based on a percentage width of the parent container? move outside the page?

Comment: @DanielTate: I mean adjust the horizontal positions. I want to keep the relative locations between the inner divs true, but the distances between them would decrease as the window width changes. It seems to me to be something I could do if I could dynamically adjust the `position:left` attribute in the css. If I could figure out how to do it, I'd provide a better example ;-).

Comment: ^ Both elements are positioned absolutely; the difference between them will always be the same, regardless of resizing of the window.

Comment: @ObsidianAge: Only if I change them by the same amount. I intend to set the new left position as a function of the window width and the previous left position. Although maybe someone can suggest a more elegant way?

Comment: What I'm saying is that your desired situation "*I want to keep the relative locations between the inner divs true*" is **already** true; you don't need to adjust anything in order to achieve that. I'm afraid I'm still **completely** confused as to what you're actually trying to achieve by adjusting the `left` values with jQuery. Perhaps diagrams of a large viewport and a small viewport would help?

Comment: @ObsidianAge: Sorry, I'm very new to web dev. I'm trying to make a [tag cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) that dynamically adjusts tag positions as the window width is changed. Think of the inner divs as floating and their actual locations are based on the window width. Ultimately, I suspect a pure Javascript approach may be most effective, but I'm trying to avoid that for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still note sure **quite** what you're looking for, but in order to modify the text offset, what you're looking to do is make use of a combination of **[`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)**, **[`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)** and **[`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**.

First check the current offset of `$('#text')`. Note that you might think that you can do this with `$('#text').css("left")`, but you'll actually need to make use of **[`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/)**.

On load, you'll need to check the current size of the window, so you can work out whether the window is getting larger or smaller (meaning you're shrinking or growing it when resizing). You can compare these values against those in `.resize()` to work out whether the window is now larger or smaller.

Finally, you can set the `left` offset of the `#text` element with `$("#text").css("left", text_offset += 10)`. Note that you increase the offset when shrinking the window, and decrease the offset when enlarging the window.

Here's an example putting all this together:

```js
var w = 0;
var text_offset = $('#text').position().left;

$(document).ready(function() {
  w = $(window).width();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  if (w > $(window).width()) {
    $("#text").css("left", text_offset += 10);
  } else {
    $("#text").css("left", text_offset -= 10);
  }
  w = $(window).width();
});
```

```css
.top {
  font: "Arial Bold";
  font-weight: bolder;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.top div {
  position: absolute;
}

#text {
  color: #c9d35f;
  top: 100px;
  left: 150px;
}

#text2 {
  color: #fa48bc;
  top: 175px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='top'>
  <div id="text">My text</div>
  <div id="text2">Other text</div>
</div>
```

I've also created a snippet showcasing this **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/0LnmkggL/)**.

Note that you'll need to play around with the offset values, probably using `1` in place of `10` (because you drag by a single pixel)!

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This effect is exactly what I was looking for when I asked the question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a percentage for the value of the `left` attribute. In your Fiddle example, you would have to change your two text selectors to have to following css declarations:

```
#text{
  color: #c9d35f;
  top: 100px;
  left: 15%;
}

#text2{
  color: #fa48bc;
  top: 175px;
  left: 30%;
}
```